# Why validation runs on field update in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know that there shouldn't be any validation on field update but it runs anyway when I try to migrate a database.

Part of the migration:

```
const arr = await User.find({ ban: { $exists: true } });
arr.forEach(async item => {
  // this works
  // await User.updateOne({ _id: item._id }, { ban: false });
  // this doesn't
  item.ban = false;
  await item.save();
});
```

Part of the schema:

```
email: {
  type: String,
  validate: {
    validator: email => User.doesntExist({ email }),
    message: ({ value }) => `Email ${value} has already been taken`
  }
}
```

"ValidationError: User validation failed: email: Email guest1@ex.com has already been taken"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option for disabling validator to be fired in mongoose `save()`, which is `validateBeforeSave`. (since mongoose version 4.4.2)

So try to use `save({ validateBeforeSave: false })` if you want to keep using `save()` instead of `update()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right, because as [reported in mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating):

> The save() function is generally the right way to update a document with Mongoose. With save(), you get full validation and middleware.

But, when you call the `.save()` function, all validators are called, including your user email validator:

```
validator: email => User.doesntExist({ email })
```

And in your case this is a problem, because the user being validated is already saved in the db... So, to avoid this you need to use the [.update()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) function in order to update your users.

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#validation

Validation is middleware. Mongoose registers validation as a pre('save') hook on every schema by default.

updateOne doesn't triggers save hook.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating doc.save works as updateOne and doesn't trigger pre('save')